# Prisma query to include categories only if they appear in an item 2 table relation

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have a table categories,

```
model publish_categories {
  c_id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name   String
  slug   String
  active Int?
}
```

then I have items, in the items table I have a categories enrty that lists multiple categories as an array

```
model publish_items{
id               Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
groups           Int[]
}
```

While there may be multiple categories under each item there may be categories with no items in them as well.  I am struggling to find a filter to only show a list of categories that have items in them via Prisma. I have not seen any way of doing an "IN" relation between the tables.

```
const categories = await prisma.publish_categories.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
      slug: true
    },
    where: {

    },
    orderBy: {
      name: "asc"
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve categories only if they have items associated with them, you can use a Prisma query that uses the some filter along with a nested relation.
In order to determine whether there is at least one item that meets the given condition, use items relation with the **'some'** filter . Only the categories with at least one associated item will be returned by this query.

This is how you can change your query.

```
const categoriesWithItems = await prisma.publish_categories.findMany({
  select: {
    id: true,
    name: true,
    slug: true,
  },
  where: {
    // Use a nested relation with count to filter categories with items
    items: {
      some: {
        // Add any additional conditions for items if needed
      },
    },
  },
  orderBy: {
    name: "asc",
  },
});
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: That would work but how can I make the relation to the stored array values is the big issue.